# What's the correct currency format in Belgian Dutch?

Tags: java, localization, currency

I'm formatting some currency in Java. This piece outputs 9,99 €

```
    final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("nl", "BE"));
    nf.setCurrency(EUR);
    nf.format(new BigDecimal("9.99"));
```

but one of our payment providers, which returns amounts preformatted, outputs € 9,99

Which is correct for `nl-BE`?

And more programming related, if it turns out the payment provider, and not Java, is correct, how do I fix the Java way without hacks per locale (in the real code the *Dutch in Belgium* locale is not hardcoded)

Comment: Belgium... Nobody agrees with each other. For this apparently also not.

Comment: Yeah. Just find how it's done in the French-speaking side, and do the reverse for the Dutch-speaking side :-) - PS: this is coming from a French-speaking Belgian living in France

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [Wikipedia is to be believed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_issues_concerning_the_euro#Dutch), neither is incorrect:

> In Belgian Dutch, the euro sign can go before or after the amount, the
>   latter being more common.

Comment: Thanks, though I just discovered my problem is bigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571164/format-currency-in-a-language-regardless-of-country

Comment: Nowadays the wikipedia says "In Dutch language print, the euro sign (€) is chiefly placed before the amount, from which it is often separated by a (thin) space"...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Nobody cares. You can use anyone.

Somewhat longer answer: If the amount appears in a sentence, 9,99 € is more usual. If it's at the bottom of an invoice, both are used. No wait, you could even use EUR instead of €.

BTW, most people even expect 9.99 € instead of 9,99€ simply because [locale data was invented 25 years late](http://www.apptranslator.com/blog/2005/08/getnumberformat-was-25-years-late.html).

Be aware though that this is the opinion of a `fr-BE` guy ;-)

This is the kind of stuff where I believe locale info tries too much to differentiate neighbouring cultures. Think of keyboards: There is a layout for `fr-FR` and one for `fr-BE`. Letters, digits and most punctuation signs are at the same position but a few characters such as <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>@</kbd> are at different position on the keyboard. WTF!