# JavaScript - Intl. Numberformatter show € before value

Tags: javascript, formatting, internationalization

When using a numberformatter in JavaScript, is it possible to format the value with the euro sign before the value?

```
this.formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-be', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

this.formatter.format(2000);
```

The code sample from above returns 2000.00€ instead of €2000.00

Comment: This does not seem to be technically wrong, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7570778/1427878 And I don’t see Intl.NumberFormat offering any additional options regarding the currency symbol position ... so I guess if you really need this, you will have to manipulate the resulting value yourself somehow.

Comment: In Standard Dutch , the currency symbol is always placed before the amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use another locale. Here's a list of [the supported ones](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry). From there, I took the belgium one (`sfb`), which renders the sign in front of the number.

   ```
   this.formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('sfb', {
     style: 'currency',
     currency: 'EUR',
     minimumFractionDigits: 2
   });

   this.formatter.format(2000);
   ```
2. Parse it yourself to move the sign in front of the string:

   ```
   var str = this.formatter.format(2000);
   var result = str.substr(str.length-1)+ str.substr(0,str.length-1)
   ```

Comment: `substr` is deprecated, we should use `substring` or `slice` methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr